# Eloquent: Using intermediary tables in chained whereHas()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relatively complex database organization which I am not able to change and optimise, unfortunately.

Long story short, here is roughly this database's organisation as relevant to my problem:

`user` → hasMany → `role_assignments` → belongsTo → `context` → belongsTo (actually a morphTo) → `course` → hasMany → `enrol` → hasMany → `user_enrolments` → belongsTo → `user`

All of these models have their own Resource, and currently I am trying to get all users as a collection, such as:

`user` → multiple with → `course` → with → `enrol` → `where('user_enrolments.userid', 'user.id')`

Here is my `UserController.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\userResource;
use App\Models\user;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class userController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return new userResource::collection(
            user::query()
            ->where(function ($q) {
                $q
                ->whereHas('role_assignments', function ($q) {
                    $q->
                    ->where('role', 'student')
                    ->whereHas('context', function ($q) {
                        $q->whereHas('course', function ($q) {
                            $q->whereHas('enrol', function ($q) {
                                // And this is where I don't know what to do.
                                // I think it should look like:
                                $q->whereHas('user_enrolments', function ($q) {
                                    $q->where('userid', 'user.id');
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                })

            ->with([
                // ...
            }])
            
            ->get()
        );
    }
```

So, I don't really know what to do about this!

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

After [Alex T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153786/11459728), I feel like I need to precise something.

First, I added the `->where('role', 'student')` line in the code above to make it look more like my own code. When I first posted I tried to skim it to make it more readable and focused on my current problem, but I may have skimmed it too much. Sorry about that.

I can easily find all of the user's courses, either through the user's enrolments, or through his role assignments. But I need information in both those intermediary tables. Ideally, my Controller would return the following JSON example:

```json
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "exampleUser1",
        otherInfoAboutThisUser: "...",
        role_assignmentsWhereTheUserIsAStudent:
            [
                {
                    id: 357,
                    role: "student",
                    courseid: 1000,
                    course:
                        {
                            id: 1000,
                            name: "Course Example",
                            user_enrolmentConcerningOnlyUser1:
                                {
                                    id: 9,
                                    timestart: 1540974600,
                                    duration: 3600,
                                    userid: 1
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                    otherRoleAssignmentsWithTheirCourses...
                },
            ]
    },
    {
        otherUserWithHisOwnCharacteristics...
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you are looking to get **all users that are enrolled on at least one course**.

In this case, I would form my query to get users which have at least one `enrol`, using Laravel's [querying relationship existence query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), with the assumption that an `erol` means that they are enroled on a course.

You only need to use `whereHas` when you need more control over the querying of a relationships existence - per your code above, you don't seem to be placing any conditions on this.

If you simply want to get users enrolled on at least one course, your query would have a form of:

```
$query = user::has('enrols')
->with([...])
->get([...])
```

If you needed users enrolled on, say, as specific course, you could do:

```
$query = user::whereHas('enrols', function ($query) {
    // Assuming you have a 'courseid' key on your enrols table
    $query->where('courseid', $requestedCourseId);
})
->with([...])
->get([...])
```

On your `user` model, you would have the `enrols` relationship defined as:

```php
public function enrols() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Enrol::class, 'user_enrolments', 'userid', 'enrolid';
}
```

This uses your `user_enrolments` which essentially serving as a pivot table for the Many to Many relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be fair, I need information in both the tables `role_assignments` (to ensure the user is a student in the desired course) and `user_enrolments` (the period during which the student is enrolled in the course). So I have a `$q->where('role', 'student')->whereHas('context', ....` hanging in there.

I hoped I could retrieve multiple `user` objects with their courses where they are only students, and in those courses, the `user_enrolments` concerning only the current user, to get their enrolment duration...

Comment: That should be possible using `->pivot`

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you for your answer and consideration.

I managed to find out how to do what I wanted to. I installed the package [Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep), to create more "direct" relationships:

File `user.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;
use DB;

class mdl_user extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships;

    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';


    public function user_enrolments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(user_enrolments::class, "userid", "id");
    }

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations(
            $this->user_enrolments(),
            (new user_enrolments)->enrol(),
            (new enrol)->course()
        );
    }

    // ...

}
```

Then, I put the desired tables in `courseResource.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class courseResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'timecreated' => $this->timecreated,
            'timemodified' => $this->timemodified,
            'requested' => $this->requested,
            'role_assignments' => role_assignmentsResource::collection(
                $this->whenLoaded('role_assignments')
            ),
            'user_enrolments' => user_enrolmentsResource::collection(
                $this->whenLoaded('user_enrolments')
            ),
        ];
    }
}
```

Next, I put most of my conditions in my `userResource.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class userResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,,
            'username' => $this->whenLoaded('username'),
            'email' => $this->email,
            'course' => courseResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('course', function() {
                return $this->course()
                ->with(['role_assignments' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('userid', $this->id);
                }])
                ->with(['user_enrolments' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('userid', $this->id);
                }])
                ->get();
            })),
        ];
    }
}
```

And finally, I call the desired tables in my `userController.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\userResource;
use App\Models\user;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class userController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // These are two example values, I will retrieve them later on from the request.
        $startEpoch = 1530332000;
        $endEpoch = 1550332000;
        return userResource::collection(
            user::query()
            ->with(['course.role_assignments' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('roleid', '=', 5);
            }])
            ->with(['course.user_enrolments' => function ($q) use ($startEpoch, $endEpoch) {
                $q->whereBetween('timestart', [$startEpoch, $endEpoch])
                ->orWhereBetween('timeEnd', [$startEpoch, $endEpoch]);
            }])->get()
        );
    }
}
```

And voilà, I finally have what I wanted to! In the end, it all came down to the right organisation of Models, Resources and Controllers.

Thanks for your help!